# Distributed Graph Search

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, distributed-computing, breadth-first-search, distributed-system

Given a huge graph that is partitioned across several nodes. Each node contains some partition of the set of vertices and global adjacency information.

What is the best way to implement to a BFS over this distributed graph, given a source vertex and the address of the node it resides on. The solution should be reliable, and fast.

Comment: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~aydin/ChapterBFS2015.pdf may be of interest.  Your best bet is to find a distributed graph library that already has implemented something and go with what it implemented.

Comment: Thanks, @btilly. I did go through that pdf before, but wasn’t able to understand the concept properly from it. I am looking for a plain english/for dummies explanation of how one would evolve the sequential BFS algorithm to work across a partitioned graph on multiple nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a *lot* of ways to make this work.  Here is a simple approach, that leverages https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce.

I will assume that there are three pools of machines available to you.

1. Your graph database
2. A distributed key/value store (eg Cassandra)
3. map/reduce workers (eg Hadoop)

Then the algorithm proceeds as follows:

```
Insert into your kv store the fact that you reached the starting vertex at `(0, Null)` where the pair is `(generation, from)`:
while not finished and last generation found new stuff:
     Do a mapreduce from your k/v store:
       map gets (vertex, (found_generation, from_vertex):
         - sends:
            if found_generation is current_generation:
                foreach new_vertex adjacent to vertex (lookup in graph db):
                    send: new_vertex: (current_generation + 1, vertex)
            else:
                send: vertex: (found_generation, from_vertex)
       reduce gets (vertex, (found1, v1), (found2, v2), ...)
           search list for sample record with minimum found
               store minimum found back in k/v store
if found target:
   recursively walk k/v store to reconstruct the path
clear k/v store of working set
return answer
```

The key is that all lookups to/from the graph and the k/v store are distributed, and all work within the map/reduce is also distributed.  The synchronization per generation is minimal.  Therefore this will do most of the work in a distributed way.

And a performance note.  In general going from a simple implementation on a single machine to a distributed machine is an order of magnitude increase in cost and resources, followed by tremendous scalability.  Going from a simple implementation to a well-optimized one tends to be 1-2 orders of magnitude improvements in performance, but you're limited to what one machine can do.  Pick carefully which approach to take.  Only be distributed if you really need to be.

Comment: Thanks, @btilly. This helps. :) Could you also add a little bit on what other approaches apart from MapReduce?

Comment: @Azeem That's a giant topic.  I just outlined the easiest one for me to think through.

Comment: No worries. I’ll keep updating the question with my findings.

Answer (score 1):

Try the builtin BFS algorithm in GraphScope, which exactly suit your need.

GraphScope is a distributed graph platform which has a number of algorithms ready to use.

Back to your question, it could be done in 3 steps:

1. Launch GraphScope cluster
2. Load the Graph
3. Run BFS over it and retrieve the result.

Here's the code

```py
import graphscope
sess = graphscope.session(num_workers=4)
graph = sess.g()
graph = graph.add_edges('/path/to/dataset')

result = graphscope.bfs(graph, src=0)
print(result.to_dataframe(selector={'id': 'v.id', 'distance': 'r'})
sess.close()
```

You could refer to [this article](https://blog.graphscope.io/how-to-run-graphscope-on-kubernetes-cluster-1c8359e29d2d) to learn how to deploy graphscope, and [this article](https://blog.graphscope.io/how-to-deploy-graphscope-by-helm-on-kubernetes-999a791918aa) to learn how to deploy by [helm](https://helm.sh).